# Running videos on JavaFX in Raspberry Pi Zero

Tags: pi-zero, video, java, javafx

I am trying to run a program which shows a simple video through mediaView and then shows a QR code that is associated with a string that the program generates on javaFX in a Raspberry Pi Zero. I have tried to follow this answer Play a video using JavaFX on Raspberry Pi but I get the following problems:

I try to install Gluon following this tutorial (https://docs.gluonhq.com/embedded/#_setting_up_the_raspberry_pi) but I get the following error message when I try to run a JavaFX application WITHOUT video which simply has a button that when pressed show "Hello World":

Error occurred during initialization of VM Server VM is only supported on ARMv7+ VFP

It seems that Gluon doesn't work with the Raspberry Pi Zero but I am not sure.I must say that in order to follow the answer mentioned above I fully reinstalled the Raspberry Pi OS so it's up to date and previously I had been able to run JavaFX applications without video but not using Gluon.

Also when trying to install the gstreamer packages they all seem to be outdated and I can't install them.

So I would be very thankful if anyone could tell me how to not only properly install Gluon on Raspberry Pi Zero but also the needed packages in order to run the video. If you see that this is impossible do you have any ideas how to replicate this program in another language in order to make it work on my Raspberry Pi Zero

Comment: Could you please include [more information](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476) about the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

Raspberry Pi Zero and "full size" older Pi's have an ARMv6 processor which has a complete different internal architecture compared to other ones with an ARMv7 or ARMv8. And indeed recent Java is not supported on this ARMv6...

Check the instruction set row in the table on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications to see which boards have which type of processor.

You can find more info on this topic on my blog: https://webtechie.be/2019/02/28/pijava-part-1-java-11-on-old-raspberry-pi